# JS files don't appear in Scripts folder

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, nuget

I have updated **jQuery** and **Twitter Bootsrap** packages using **Nuget** but it removed their JS files from **Scripts** folder, and the re-installation doesn't help. I.e. I have these scripts in **packages** folder but not in **Scripts** and don't know how to use it or how to fix this bug (if it's an error).
What problem can be?

Answer (score 0):

The problem was in VCS, I had old packages that was versioned. So after "pull" old version packages were restored because I hadn't commit yet and both versions of packages were stored in folder.
**Nuget** couldn't decide which version should be used seeing few versions of the package.
**P.S.** Maybe someone will meet same problem, at least he will know a starting point for troubleshooting.